# Can not declare JSONObject type even added maven repository for it in the gradle with Intellij

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea

I added https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json into my gradle config like following:

```
allprojects {
    ...

    repositories {
        maven { url = 'https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json'}
        ...
    }
}
```

release ref link: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json/20180813

however, I wasn't able to import json by type in `import org.json` or `import javax.json`...

Anyone know why I can't import it? Because I am trying to use this type call `JSONObject`
[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should rather (unless you need to use `JSONObject` in `build.gradle` itself):

```
allprojects {
   repositories {
      mavenCentral()
   }
   dependencies {
      compile group: 'org.json', name: 'json', version: '20180813'
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You've just added *a* repository(?).  You haven't explicitly requested anything from it yet.

Instead of doing it like that, Gradle comes with `mavenCentral` as a default repository.  So all you need to do to get a dependency from it is declare it in your dependencies block.

```
apply plugin: 'java-library'

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.json:json:20180813'
}
```